# How can I select rows with repeating values

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

Is there a way to filter for rows in polars dataframe that allows for repeated values (this would be useful I think in block bootstrapping).  What I have in mind is an example dataframe:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'x':[0,1,2,3,4,5],
    'y':[10,11,12,13,14,15],
    'z':[0,0,1,1,2,2]
})
```

Giving

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ x   ┆ y   ┆ z   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 10  ┆ 0   │
│ 1   ┆ 11  ┆ 0   │
│ 2   ┆ 12  ┆ 1   │
│ 3   ┆ 13  ┆ 1   │
│ 4   ┆ 14  ┆ 2   │
│ 5   ┆ 15  ┆ 2   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Where I would like to select for example:

```
z_select = [0,1,1]
```

And getting a dataframe

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ x   ┆ y   ┆ z   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 10  ┆ 0   │
│ 1   ┆ 11  ┆ 0   │
│ 2   ┆ 12  ┆ 1   │
│ 3   ┆ 13  ┆ 1   │
│ 2   ┆ 12  ┆ 1   │ # Note this is a repeat b/c z_select has two 1s
│ 3   ┆ 13  ┆ 1   │ # Note this is a repeat b/c z_select has two 1s
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Your example is not quite clear to me, but a `pl.when` with [`is_unique`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.is_unique.html#polars.Expr.is_unique) is where I would start.

Comment: Turn that `z_select` into a dataframe and use `merge()` to join `z_select` and `df` together: `newDF = pd.DataFrame(z_select, columns=['z']).merge(df, how='inner', on='z')`

Comment: That is helpful @JNevill, thank you, I'll propose a solution based on your suggestion

Comment: You could also flip flop `df`/derived-dataframe to preserve the order of the columns, if that's important. `newDF = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(z_select, columns=['z']), how='inner', on='z')`

Comment: are you just trying to get values of your original df where the z column is either 0 or 1 and you have a redundant 1 in the `z_select` list?

Comment: In this case trying to allow for repeated samples to facilitate sampling with replacement in a bootstrapping routine

Comment: I see so the redundant 1 is meant to be repeated.

Comment: yes that's right, the use case for this I think is block bootstrapping, so allowing that some blocks will be omitted, while others will be repeated in a given resampling

Answer (score 3):

based on suggestion from @jnevill, this produces the desired dataframe:

```
pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'z':z_select
    }

).join(df, how='inner', on='z')
```

Which gives:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ z   ┆ x   ┆ y   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 10  │
│ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 11  │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 12  │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 12  │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 13  │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 13  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: I really like that you ignored the pandas syntax and went straight to the correct polars syntax (ie join instead of merge, and on instead of columns)

Answer (score -1):

No polars required, just iterate the data filters and use `pd.concat` to merge all selections.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x':[0,1,2,3,4,5],
    'y':[10,11,12,13,14,15],
    'z':[0,0,1,1,2,2]
})

def selectRepeat(df, column, data):
  res = []
  for i in data:
    res.append(df[df[column] == i])
  return pd.concat(res)

# usage
selectRepeat(df, 'z', [0,1,1])
```

Comment: The question is tagged polars so, of course, polars is required.